# Consider vectorization and for loop, do both approaches have the same time complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, python

I am learning this [post](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms)

> Fast computation of nearest neighbors is an active area of research in machine learning. The most naive neighbor search implementation involves the brute-force computation of distances between all pairs of points in the dataset: for N samples in D dimensions, this approach scales as $O[D N^2]$.

Consider knn on [iris dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris), which has 150 samples of 4 dimensions.

Here are 2 pieces of Python3 code.

code_1: vectorization

```
(np.sqrt(np.sum(X*X,axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2*np.dot(X,Y.T) 
             + np.sum(Y*Y,axis=1)[np.newaxis, :])).reshape((-1,))
```

code_2: for loop

```
[np.sqrt((X[0]-Y[0])**2 + (X[1]-Y[1])**2 +
    (X[2]-Y[2])**2 + (X[3]-Y[3])**2) for Y in trainData]
```

Do both vectorization and for loop have the same time complexity $O[D N^2]$?

The analysis does not have to be based on Python; C or C++ is also appreciated.

This question is code-independent, it is not about how Python implements some operations. it is only about 2 approaches for matrix operations, vectorization and for loop.

Comment: I don't think that analyzing the running time of Python3 code is on-topic here, as that depends on  implementation specifics about how Python implements those operations, and coding questions (like this seems to be) are off-topic here.  If you can tell us what the running time of each primitive operation is and give us pseudocode for the two methods, we might be able to help.

Comment: The reason that vectorization is so much faster than a loop in Python is very Python-specific. Under the hood, vectorization is implemented as a loop.